# AWS Route 53 - 2 hosted zones (AUS & USA) and 1 domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one Beanstalk application that is connected to a loadbalancer and being routed via Route 53 and an elastic IP. This system that works perfectly.

app.example.com points to a hosted AWS zone in Sydney (AUStralia)

The reason why it is deployed in Sydney is to avoid latency for Australian customers.

Is there a way that US customers will only use an USA EC2 instance and the Australian ones only use the AUS EC2 instance but have only 1 domain name? (app.example.com) What is the best strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [geolocation routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo) is for.  Create a record for your hostname in Route53 to your US EC2 instance, and choose "geolocation" for the routing policy, "Default" for the location.  Create another record for the same hostname, choosing "geolocation" again for the routing policy, then "Australia" for the location.

Comment: That is brilliant. I didn't know this product existed. Thanks for the quick answer.